# Непонятная ошибка при установки app android studio

Tags: android, install

При установке приложения на эмуляторе возникла непонятная ошибка и установка не прошла:

```
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
Error while Installing APKs
```

Хотя вчера все устанавливалось и работало нормально, я уже перезагрузил эмулятор но это не помогло. Кто знает в чем проблема помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: подобная ошибка может возникнуть, если не включен режим  отладки по usb, но это не точно

Comment: на эмуляторе вчера все работало нормально, а сегодня какая-то фигня произошла)) не могу понять почему, я ведь еще не начал менять что-то.

Comment: эмулятор от genymotion или от Android Studio?

Comment: genymotion, потому-что android studio тяжелая очень для эмуляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как на странно но мне помог такой способ, надеюсь поможет кому-то тоже:

1. меню "Build" -> "Clean Project".
2. меню "Build" -> "Rebuild Project".